# Serializing a class to xml using RestSharp.AddBody fails

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, serialization, restsharp

I try to add a simple test-class to a `RestSharp-RestRequest` via the `RestRequest.AddBody`-Method. I tried to serialize using both of the delivered serializers, but i could not get one of them to work (JSON-Serializations works pretty fine with just the same settings...)

This is how i do the serialization:

```
private void SerializationTest()
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

    request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer();
    //request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer();

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
    //request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(new Dummy()); // uses JsonSerializer

    label1.Text = request.Parameters[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

The dummy-class I'm using is:

```
private class Dummy
{
    public string A = "Some string";
    public string B = "Some string";
}
```

1. Using `RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer()` I get: "`<Dummy />`" (missing both strings)
2. Using `RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer()` I get nothing, the programm just dosen't get over the serialization-step.
3. Using JSON `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;`, everything works fine.

.

```
{  
    "A": "Some string",  
    "B": "Some string"  
}
```

How do i get the class so serialize proper to XML?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are fields, not properties. The underlying XmlSerializer only looks for public properties. Update it to this and it should work:

```
class Dummy
{
    public string A { get; set; };
    public string B { get; set; };

    public Dummy() {
        A = "Some string";
        B = "Some string";
    }
}
```

The reason the JSON one works is because it defers to JSON.NET's default serializer which (apparently) supports fields. I think this is the wrong design decision personally.