# How to call Rest ful webservice using httpWebRequest and PostData

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I have created a restful webservice like below

**Opertation Contract**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/PushNotification")]
        [OperationContract]
        void PushNotification(MailInformation mailInformations);
```

**MailInformations class**

```
 [DataContract]
    public class MailInformation
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> To { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string SenderEmail { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i call this service using HttpWebrequest ?

**My Service Url**

localhost/Chat/ChatService.svc/PushNotification

Comment: this is a rest service. I think rest service doesn't proxy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MailInformation mi = new MailInformation(){
    SenderEmail = "aaa@bbb.com",
    Subject = "test",
    To = new List<string>(){"ccc@eee.com"}
};

var dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mi));

var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Chat/ChatService.svc/PushNotification");

req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.ContentLength = dataToSend.Length;
req.Method = "POST";
req.GetRequestStream().Write(dataToSend,0,dataToSend.Length);

var response = req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: in which namespace JsonConvert  class?

Comment: Sorry.. I used [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) But  you can also use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: But in the service mailInformations are null..How can i get this parameter?

Comment: @JEMI try `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` instead of `WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped`

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself the hassle of using `HttpWebRequest` and just use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost");
var request = new RestRequest("Chat/ChatService.svc/PushNotification");
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

Comment: @JEMI here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312970/restsharp-json-parameter-posting

Comment: @JEMI you can also post the object directly if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966521/restsharp-post-object-to-wcf